# Echo don't load (and bug jquery)

Tags: laravel, echo

I got my archive main.js, and I put the archive in template.blade.php, I put the pusher.js in template:

```
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/3.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

My main.js:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
    {
        var container = $(".to-hide");
        var container2 = $(".to-close");

        if ($(".no-close").length){

        } else {

        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
        {
            container.hide();
        }

        if (!container2.is(e.target) && container2.has(e.target).length === 0) 
        {
            container2.remove();
        }
        }
    });

     //import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

     window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

     window.Echo = new Echo({
         broadcaster: 'pusher',
         key: 'MY-KEY'
     });
```

When I remove comment of //import... the jquery don't work, and don't import the echo, why?

Console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```